# Регулярные выражения в JavaScript

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

У меня есть такая строка

```
var str = "example1 example2 example3 .... exampleN";
```

ну вы поняли смысл. Я не знаю, в строке str сколько слов. Мне нужно выбрать только первую (в смысле до первого пробела). Чтобы после функц. я получил "example1".

Comment: <a href="http://www.ozhegov.ru/">http://www.ozhegov.ru/</a> - это всё, чем я вам могу помочь

Comment: зачем мне словарь??я не русский,по этому много орфографичиские и граммат. ошибки

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А почему не воспользоваться методом split()? Хотя цикл тоже нормальный, он сразу находит первый нужный элемент и заканчивает работу, просто кода многовато, можно проще

```
var str = "example1 example2 example3 .... exampleN";
            str = str.split(' '); //отделит все что с пробелом
            console.log(str[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var str = new Array('ex1', 'ex2', 'ex3');
    document.write(str[0]);
</script>
```

Comment: У вас первоначально известно, что 3 значения, я уже нашел решение, писал функцию

    var str = "example1 example2 example4 example45 and so";
    var n = str.length;
    var j;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (str[i] == " ") {
            j = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    alert(str.substr(0, j));